# How can I pass foreign characters (e.g. æ) to a javascript array from a PHP array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array of file paths, which is stored in a PHP array called $files, which I would like to pass to a javascript array using this command:

```
 var files = <?php echo json_encode($files)?>;
```

Which is fine, however it doesn't pass any values which have special characters for example one that contains 'æ'. Instead that value in Javascript comes out as null. Is there another way of preserving these characters? The values are all file paths, which seem to be passed over OK using json_encode, just not these special characters.

Comment: Maybe try wrapping each file path in htmlentities call, this should display all special chars correctly and allow you to pass it back to php and get original path using html-entity-decode

$filesEncoded = array_map($files, function ($e) { return htmlentities($e)})
<?php echo json_encode($filesEncoded)?>;

Comment: Can you show me some more info on how to do that? Each path is collected automatically via another function, but if you can tell me how to encode each filepath, I can insert that in before it appends that path onto the PHP $files array.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work anyway, I've got this line straight after i've populated my $files array:    $filesEncoded = array_map($files, function ($e) { return htmlentities($e); }) but I get this error: "Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members" for that line.

Comment: You're right, I didn't check it. My bad, array_map takes callback as first argument and array as second. Intuitive as always. Glad you've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. I essentially ran through the array using url_encode, and THEN JSON'd that for Javascript to interpret.

```
$filesEncoded = array();
foreach ($files as $f) {
    array_push($filesEncoded,urlencode($f));
}
<script>
    var files = <?php echo json_encode($filesEncoded)?>;
</script>
```